# Work-arounds Installation to other hard drive?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management

I have a small NVMe card containing the root directory of my arch-linux installation. My goal is to boot up using the NVMe, and more or less, use my big hard drive for everything else. Especially the installation of packages.

In Windows, when I install something, I am usually given the option of where to install it, so I can choose the big hard drive. But in arch-linux, what options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory hierarchy is already set out for this, if you have separate `/usr` (some distro unify `/usr/bin` and `/bin`, but can often be re-configured).

The stuff in `/usr`, `/home`, `/opt` is not needed at boot time. So you can put the rest on the boot media, and mount these from else where.